# Why is the Desktop API throw a NPE when app is ran as Java Web Start?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, desktop, java-web-start

I have only be working with Java for about 6 months, so I definitely a newbie. Also, I did post this question on the Oracle Technical Network Community a few days ago, but have heard nothing.

The application I have been developing is being beta tested currently via web start. We thought this was the best way to keep users up to date with the latest bug fixes. I guess I should mention it is a JavaFX app that uses Maven. In the application, I'm using the OPEN and MAIL actions of the Desktop API. The OPEN action is being used to open the system folder browser. This is the action I need to get working. The MAIL action is more for user convenience. Both work fine when running the application from the executable jar, but I get a NPE for both when the app is launched through web start. It passes the isDesktopSupported test. Everything is signed with a verified DigiCert certificate and has all-permissions set. When the app first launchs it creates a folder and config file in the user home directory with no problem.

I created a small demo app to make sure there wasn't something elsewhere in my app causing the problem, but I get the exact same error. The code I'm posting is from the demo app.

FXMLController.java

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink hyperlink;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        if (Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) { //NPE thrown here
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        } else {
        System.out.println("The OPEN action is not supported on your current platform.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Desktop class is not supported on your current platform.");
    }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLinkAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        if (Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) { //NPE thrown here
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI("mailto:email@testing.yes"));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        } else {
        System.out.println("The MAIL action is not supported on your current platform.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Desktop class is not supported on your current platform.");
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }
}
```

JNLP file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jnlp spec="1.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="DesktopClassTesting.jnlp">  
    <information>  
  <title>DesktopClassTesting</title>  
  <vendor>USGS</vendor>  
    </information>  
    <security>  
  <all-permissions/>  
    </security>  
    <update check="always" policy="always" />  
    <resources>  
  <j2se version="1.7.0_60+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />  
  <jar href="DesktopClassTesting.jar" main="true" version="0.1-SNAPSHOT"/>  
  <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>  
    </resources>  
    <application-desc name="Desktop Class Testing"/>  
    <jfx:javafx-desc main-class="gov.usgs.tnm.desktopclasstesting.MainApp" name="MainApp"/>  
</jnlp>
```

OPEN action stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)  
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  ... 48 more  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
  at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Unknown Source)  
  at gov.usgs.tnm.desktopclasstesting.FXMLController.handleButtonAction(FXMLController.java:30)  
  ... 57 more
```

MAIL action stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)  
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)  
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)  
  ... 48 more  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
  at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Unknown Source)  
  at gov.usgs.tnm.desktopclasstesting.FXMLController.handleLinkAction(FXMLController.java:51)  
  ... 57 more
```

I can post the FXML file and MainApp.java if need be. I've been working on this for a days with no success, so any insight would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I note the app. is using Java-FX.  Perhaps the AWT (e.g. `Desktop`) classes are not properly initialized due to it being Java-FX based. (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was a known bug that was corrected in the recent release of Java 7_65 and Java 8_11. Here is a link to the bug description in the database.

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8019274